# Error in connection string, how to connect Prisma to Azure SQL database

Tags: sql-server, prisma, azure-sql-server, prisma-graphql

The JDBC connection string you provide for Prisma ORM for connecting to Azure SQL database has special characters (as username ends with `@<server>` and passwords might have them too), how to escape them properly? This is the error I was getting:

```
❯ npx prisma migrate deploy
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db"
Error: undefined: Database error
Authentication failed for user user%40server
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **escape values by putting them inside curly braces**, like `key={value@something};`. This passes the values with special characters correctly.